# Creating an explosion in panda3d and blender

Tags: python, blender, panda3d

hi im quite new to panda3d and python (1year)and iv been trying for longer then 4months to find out how to create a simple mesh explosion in panda 3d.
iv created lots of different explosions using blender and they all look good and work fine in blender but when i export them through .x or .egg files the animation is always blank.  i know panda normally uses armature to do animations but with a mesh explosion on a space ship or box or any static object it does not have armature and maybe this is why it never really exports the visaul effect...
iv been trying so long now just to explode anything but cannot work out how to go about this?? its really getting me down as the particle effects panel is great for things like smoke and fire etc but i want to see the actual mesh and faces explode into pieces so i can continue working and learning how to create and develop games.

iv looked into everything on the web and blender and pand3d but cant find anyone or anything that has had this problem or solution.

I hate to ask but i cant give up now iv learnt so much in the last year,  is there anyone who could help me with this?? it would be very much appreciated!!!

iv got demo code but im not sure how to upload the models iv created. do you need to see it?? as its not the code that is the problem but the eggs and blender??

the models iv created have seperate animation files and iv tried animation files within the ,egg.
iv got other animated models to work so i know its not that, like i said iv tried everything to get my ship to explode .... please help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I guess you could try to ask this question in the https://blender.stackexchange.com/ network.